# After counting number of days between two dates(taken from edittext) how to show days into new edittext

Tags: java, android, date

Please Solve my problem i am try this code from last week but the app crashes says"Unfortunately project has stopped".

```
public void Daysss_check() {
    ed5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    ed6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String firstDate = ed2.getText().toString(); 
    String secondDate = ed5.getText().toString();
    try {
        date1 = myFormat.parse(firstDate); 
        date2 = myFormat.parse(secondDate);
    } 
    catch (ParseException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    float diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    float dayCount = (float) diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);ed6.setText((int) dayCount);
}
```

Comment: Please post stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ed6.setText(""+((int) dayCount));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a CharSequence to setText, so use:

```
String.valueOf((int) dayCount)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try to convert float into `String` like this

```
ed6.setText(Float.toString(dayCount));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 ed2.setText(String.valueOf(dayCount));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can set text

```
public void Daysss_check() {
    ed5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    ed6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String firstDate = ed2.getText().toString();
    String secondDate = ed5.getText().toString();
    try {
        date1 = myFormat.parse(firstDate);
        date2 = myFormat.parse(secondDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    float diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    float dayCount = (float) diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    String myDaycount = String.valueOf(dayCount)
    ed6.setText(myDaycount);
}
```